# How to get exact number in set of numbers using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have implementing program in command line and i written code like this:

```
import requests
import re
import sys

amount=[]
l=len(sys.argv)
from_=sys.argv[l-2]
to=sys.argv[l-1]
for i in range(1,l-2):
    amount.append(sys.argv[i])
for i in amount:
    r = requests.get("http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert/?Amount=%(amount)s&From=%(from_)s&To=%(to)s"%{"amount":i,"from_":from_,"to":to})
    #dataCrop=re.findall('[0-9,]+\.[0-9]+',r.text)
    dataCrop=re.compile(r'[0-9,]+\.[0-9]+')
    for m in dataCrop.finditer(r.text):
        print m.group()
```

When I run the program I got output like this:

```
1.0
1.1
3.43
1.1
1.1
1.1
1999.09
1.1
1999.09
4.7
1.00
55.6565
55.6565
0.0179674
1.00000
0.79649
0.63231
55.6565
0.96365
0.98866
8.42406
1.24172
78.5433
1.00000
1.25551
1.58151
0.01797
1.03772
1.01147
0.11871
0.80533
0.01273
0.01797
0.01431
0.01136
1.00000
0.01731
0.01776
0.15136
0.02231
1.41122
55.6565
69.8771
88.0212
1.00000
57.7556
56.2947
6.60685
44.8219
0.70861
9.4
2.0
```

But i want output '55.6565'(which is in 12th position and in array 11th position) only this much.How I should modify my regular expression?

Comment: If you only want `55.6565` in your results, then do `r.text.count('55.6565')`

Comment: Its dynamic program this value keep changing. This is answer for '1'.If I give '2' then it will 111.some value.

Comment: so you want `r.text.count(str(55.6565*<some number>))`?

Comment: Can you give a more general rule to identify the number you need to be output?

Comment: <td width="47%" align="left">55.6565&nbsp;<span class="uccResCde">USD</span><!-- WARNING: Automated extraction of rates is prohibited under the Terms of Use. -->
</td> this is the tag where my answer is there. 55.6565 will give the answer when I give value 1 in command line that is p programname.py 1 USD INR. When i give p programname.py 2 USD INR it will give answer 111.385 according to currency. Now my problem is how I can extract this value using regular expression. I cant use beautiful soup.Can anyone help me out for this?

Comment: You should probably look at this text: *WARNING: Automated extraction of rates is prohibited under the Terms of Use.*.

Comment: [The foregoing prohibitions expressly include, but are not limited to, the practice of "screen scraping", or any other practice or activity the purpose of which is to obtain lists of data, portions of a database, or other lists or information from the Services, in any manner or in any quantities not authorized in writing by XE.](http://www.xe.com/legal/). In other words, you need to [pay for this kind of stuff](http://www.xe.com/dfs/product.php).

Answer (score 0):

You have to **purchase** their service. When you do, you'll have to deal with a different format of data, but the general idea from the programming perspective will be the same.

First, you need to match the right line in the HTML you get. Then you search inside the string for what looks like a number in the right context, making sure you capture the actual number into a group. Then you are done. For the HTML in question:

```
for line in r.text.split('\n'):  # This splits the entire HTML into lines.
  if re.search(r'<span class="uccResCde">INR</span>', line):
    match = re.search(r'>(?P<number>[0-9]+.[0-9]+)', line)
    if not match:
      raise Exception('Expected to find a number but did not.')
    print match.group('number')
```

This outputs:

```
55.5211
```